# Turing machine sequence of configurations

Tags: turing-machines

hello I have written the sequence of configurations for the following Turing machine for input 00 but my answer has been marked wrong and I'm not sure where I have gone wrong I have fried it 3 times.

[image]

this is the turning machine

[image]

Comment: The computation history needs to contain the 3 following things: 1) the position of the head 2) the current state of the machine 3) the (entire) contents of the tape. But I can only see one of those things (the current state) in your prescribed "solution"

Comment: Also, if your answer has been marked wrong then I think its best to ask your teacher. You might have learned this in a different way than what I and others here have, so for your better understanding it would be best if you could ask your teacher for clarifications.

Comment: In $(\varepsilon, q_3,1)$ you have to move Left. It seems you moved Right?